# Running bat file with java

Tags: java, processbuilder

here i'm trying to run a bat file from a java program.
i want to run the bat file from c:\File\Create.bat but when i run the code
it's searching in my d:\NetBeansPeoject\test.java
where my java program is located, why??

here the code:

```
try
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\File\\Create.bat");
   Process p = pb.start();

}
catch (IOException e)
 {
e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> With [ProcessBuilder](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html), you call start()
>   to execute the command. Prior to
>   calling start(), you can manipulate
>   how the Process will be created. If
>   you want the process to start in a
>   different directory, you don't pass a
>   File in as a command line argument.
>   Instead, you set the process builder's
>   working directory by passing the File
>   to the directory() method:

```
   public ProcessBuilder directory(File directory)
```